# Jquery UI Tabs Not Working With Custom CSS

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Below is a jsfiddle link to my code. I do not have any JQuery UI Default CSS styling (I'm using custom styling for everything) and I assume that this is the issue. Thanks for the help

http://jsfiddle.net/B2rJW/1/

Comment: @msr , you css is getting applied , you can check the same with firebug..

Comment: I know the CSS is getting applied but the tabs are still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customise the CSS, it's probably easier if you edit a copy of the original CSS, instead of generating a brand new one yourself.

It might be easier to fiddle with CSS with jsbin.com, as it gives you the full page of the result, which you can then use a inspector (e.g. Firebug or Safari's Web Inspector) and adjust the CSS to your heart's content. http://jsbin.com/ihizo5

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i did notice that you aren't using the latest version of jquery, there is 1.5.1. Secondly there is a much easier way to apply your own css styling to jQuery UI widgets. Go to their [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and apply your own styles. Its a great to tool tweak the styles.

Comment: Thanks I knew about this, but I am working off of a PSD file and this seemed like the esiest way to work. (as apposed to overriding all the rules). Do you know of an easier way?

Comment: No sorry. My answer would probably be my advice because then you know that you have covered everything. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load jQuery **before** jQuery-ui.

**Before:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**After:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some more dependencies

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

to your jsfiddle, copied them off:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
then it worked and applied all necessary classes.
Also I suggest you to add a basic style from jquery ui, and then apply your own css after that, else it will still appear as if it is not working.

Lauw